# Unresolved reference to object for index hint in SSDT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I have function DDL that I can successfully that I can easily create manually using SSMS, however I can't build/publish project as it complains that there is unresolved reference. The issue is with index hint (**please don't say that hints are bad, I know that**).

I've minimized the query to be short, just to show what exactly is not working:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[function] 
        ()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(   
           SELECT 1 as one
             FROM dbo.tbl l with (index (ndx_acct))
)
```

The dbo.tbl is actually synonym and it points to another database on the same instance.

The error message:

> Error     SQL71501: Function: [dbo].[function]  contains an unresolved
>   reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the
>   reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following
>   objects: [dbo].[tbl].[ndx_acct] or [dbo].[ndx_acct].

Comment: It sounds like you just need to prefix `ndx_acct` to be more specific. Does changing it to `[dbo].[tbl].[ndx_acct]` resolve the issue?

Comment: no, it doesn't work. It complains to the syntax error

Comment: Rename your index to something else. Looks like you a table (or some other object) with the same name as your index. It is good idea to prefix your index names with "IX_"

Comment: @Alex That didn't help

Comment: Do you have a database reference to that other database for the synonym to work?

Comment: yes. This database is added as "the same instance, different database" and in synonym I have something like "create synonym dbo.tbl FOR [$(dbname)].dbo.tbl. This synonym is working as if I remove index hint then I get no complains